# why rectangle selector can't moved inside plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

i have app when i have add a rectangle selector but is can't moved when i click in 
and i need to plot the area inside the rectangle in other frame how can i do that ?
i think something is wrong in my code the rectangle is can't moved in plot i cant move it !!
and after how i can plot the area select in other frame ?

thanks you all

```
import wx
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4





def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    #print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))


class Window(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, **kwargs)
        RootPanel(self)



class RootPanel(wx.Panel):


    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        panel_buttons = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_buttons_sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)

        select_button = PickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc",
            canvas_panel.load_from_file,
            label="Show on this window (nc)",
        )
        toplevel_select_button = TopLevelPickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "Text files (txt)|*.txt|All files|*.*",
            label="Show on separate window (txt)",
        )
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(select_button)
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(toplevel_select_button)
        panel_buttons.SetSizer(panel_buttons_sizer)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel_buttons)
        sizer.Add(canvas_panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class PickButton(wx.Button):


    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, func, **kwargs):
        # func est la méthode à laquelle devra être foruni le fichier sélectionné
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.wildcard = wildcard
        self.func = func
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pick_file)

    def pick_file(self, evt):
        style = style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.FD_MULTIPLE
        with wx.FileDialog(
            self, "Pick files", wildcard=self.wildcard, style=style
        ) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() != wx.ID_CANCEL:
                chosen_file = fileDialog.GetPath()
                self.func(chosen_file)


class TopLevelPickButton(PickButton):


    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, wildcard, self.create_toplevel, **kwargs)

    def create_toplevel(self, file_name):
        """ Ouvre une toplevel et affiche le graphique """
        self.win = TopLevelCanvas(self.Parent)
        self.win.canvas_panel.load_from_file(file_name)
        self.win.Show()


class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(8,7))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size

    def load_from_file(self, file_name):
        """

        son type
        """
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        if file_name.endswith(".nc"):
            self._load_nc(file_name)
        else:
            self._load_txt(file_name)
        self.canvas.draw()

    #print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))
    def _load_nc(self, file_name):

        t = np.arange(0.0, 8.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(3 * np.pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)



        # drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
        RS = RectangleSelector(self.axes,line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                       button=[3],  
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)


        RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)
        RS.extents = (1,20,1,15)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
        plt.show()

class TopLevelCanvas(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.Size = self.canvas_panel.Size


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        win = Window(title="A test dialog", size=(1000, 800))
        win.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove `plt.show()`, which doesn't make sense here anyways?

Comment: when i remove plt.show() nothing happened i cant moved the rectangle select !!

Comment: Ok,remove it anyways. Also make `RS` an instance variable, like you did with the other objects, `self.RS`.

Comment: that is good is moved the rectangle is moved i'm  add self in the lines : `self.RS = RectangleSelector.....
        self.RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)
        self.RS.extents ,self.figure.canvas.draw()` but i have question how can remove the color red inside rectangle ? transparent rectangle ? thanks u

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest why the rectangle does move fast how can i make the rectangle selector move fast ? thank you for the help

Comment: i find how remove color i add `.. rectprops = dict(facecolor='green', edgecolor = 'black', alpha=0.2, fill=True))` but still don't know how make rectangleselector  move fast !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle is moved by dragging the Square box in the middle of the rectangle.
I'm sure that there are many ways with `matplotlib` to draw the selected rectangle in another plot, a sort of manual zoom but I'm no `matplotlib` expert by any means.
The following achieves what I think you want by storing the axis of the rectangle selection and then calls a new frame, where the plot is repeated but with the adjusted axis.
The new frame is self cancelling if it loses focus, so you don't end up with multiple `Zoom` windows.
Hope it helps!

```
import wx
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib

class Window(wx.Frame):
    """ Fenêtre principale de l'application """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, **kwargs)
        RootPanel(self)



class RootPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel contenant tous les autres widgets de l'application """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        panel_buttons = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_buttons_sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)

        select_button = PickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc",
            canvas_panel.load_from_file,
            label="Show on this window (nc)",
        )
        toplevel_select_button = TopLevelPickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "Text files (txt)|*.txt|All files|*.*",
            label="Show on separate window (txt)",
        )
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(select_button)
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(toplevel_select_button)
        panel_buttons.SetSizer(panel_buttons_sizer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel_buttons)
        sizer.Add(canvas_panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class PickButton(wx.Button):
    """ Bouton permettant de choisir un fichier """

    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, func, **kwargs):
        # func est la méthode à laquelle devra être foruni le fichier sélectionné
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.wildcard = wildcard
        self.func = func
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pick_file)

    def pick_file(self, evt):
        style = style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.FD_MULTIPLE
        with wx.FileDialog(
            self, "Pick files", wildcard=self.wildcard, style=style
        ) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() != wx.ID_CANCEL:
                chosen_file = fileDialog.GetPath()
                self.func(chosen_file)


class TopLevelPickButton(PickButton):
    """ Permet de choisir un fichier et d'ouvrir une toplevel """

    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, wildcard, self.create_toplevel, **kwargs)

    def create_toplevel(self, file_name):
        """ Ouvre une toplevel et affiche le graphique """
        self.win = TopLevelCanvas(self.Parent)
        self.win.canvas_panel.load_from_file(file_name)
        self.win.Show()


class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(8,7))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.zoom_axis = []

    def load_from_file(self, file_name):
        """
        Méthode effectuant l'intermédiaire pour charger le fichier selon
        son type
        """
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        if file_name.endswith(".nc"):
            self._load_nc(file_name)
        else:
            self._load_txt(file_name)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def _load_txt(self, file_name):
        self._load_nc(file_name)

    def _load_nc(self, file_name):
        """ Simule le chargement et affichage à partir d'un fichier nc """
        t = np.arange(0.0, 8.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(3 * np.pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)



    # drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'

        self.RS = RectangleSelector(self.axes,self.line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True, rectprops = dict(facecolor='None',edgecolor='red',alpha=5,fill=False))


        #self.RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)
        #self.figure.canvas.draw()
        #self.RS.extents = (0,1,0,1)

    def line_select_callback(self, eclick, erelease):
        'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
        x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
        self.zoom_axis=[x1,x2,y1,y2]
        Zoom(parent=self)


class Zoom(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,("Zoom"))
        self.parent = parent

        #Make this zoom window self cancelling if it loses focus
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, self.OnExit)

        #Load axis values of the selected rectangle
        zoom_axis=parent.zoom_axis

        #duplicate the plot from the main panel
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(8,7))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        """ Simule le chargement et affichage à partir d'un fichier nc """
        t = np.arange(0.0, 8.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(3 * np.pi * t)

        #Apply axis of drawn rectangle to the plot
        self.axes.axis(zoom_axis)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        focus = event.GetActive()
        if focus == False: # Window lost focus
            self.Close()

class TopLevelCanvas(wx.Frame):
    """ Fenêtre affichant uniquement un graph matplotlib """

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.Size = self.canvas_panel.Size


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        win = Window(title="A test dialog", size=(1000, 800))
        win.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: i have problem with my app

Comment: i have tthis error when i run code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\majdoulina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 215, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\majdoulina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 1597, in release
    self._release(event)
  File "C:\Users\majdoulina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 2194, in _release self.onselect(self.eventpress, self.eventrelease) TypeError: line_select_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'erelease'

Comment: Your code had the function `line_select_callback(eclick, erelease)` defined outside of the class, I moved it into the `CanvasPanel` class. I suspect that that is where the problem lies because once it is within the class, it expects 3 parameters `self`, `eclick` and `erelease`.

Comment: the problem i m applicat your code in second app the code is code for the first but when i do the same for the second app that work but when i select rectangelselector to plot zoom frame that give me the error is her my second app [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889431/error-when-select-area-inside-rectangle-class-zoomwx-frame] if you can help thank you in advance

Comment: is possible to add zoom inside second panel if i add second panel rightpanel and i change zoom(wxframe) to zoom(wx.panel ) it possible to do that ?! thank you again