# wxpython can't choose the good panel for zoom

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

I have this app in wxpython when I select the panel when I need to plot zoom the wxpython can't plot in the correct panel the plot up in the same panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to start?
In `LeftPanelBottom` you have defined

```
canvas_panel = LeftPanelTop(self)
self.canvas_panel = LeftPanelTop(self)
self.zoom_panel = MiddlePanelTop(parent=self)
```

So that is 2 canvas panels, followed by `sizer` confusion and the fact that you placed `MiddlePanelTop` slap bang inside of `LeftPanelBottom` along with `LeftPanelTop` which has already been loaded into `LeftPanel`.

But the main issue is about `inheritance`. Because just about everything is defined as a `class` in its own right, even buttons, trying to find a path through to the `MiddlePanelTop` escapes me. Perhaps someone else can chime in here, as I got lost.
The simple and apparently un-pythonic way is to just use a `global` variable.
Below, I use a `global` called `Zoom`.
N.B. I have also changed the `path` to the file, where appropriate

Edit:
I have de-coded your classes within classes and added in the appropriate `self` entries, which allows us to access them.
As a result the `Left` panel now functions as I suppose you intended as well.
I note that the `Right` and `MiddlePanelBottom` panels still have inconsistencies, missing items and fixed positioning.

```
import wx
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
#Zoom = None


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        super().__init__(parent,title= "quick",name="Main", size = (2000,1000))

        self.left = LeftPanel(self)
        self.middle = MiddlePanel(self)
        self.right = RightPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.left, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.middle, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.right, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


# ------------ LEFT ------------
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="Left", style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.top = LeftPanelTop(self)
        self.bottom = LeftPanelBottom(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.top, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class LeftPanelTop(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="LeftTop", size = (510,350))
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(5,3))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size

    def load_from_file(self, file_name):
        """
        Méthode effectuant l'intermédiaire pour charger le fichier selon
        son type
        """
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        if file_name.endswith(".nc"):
            self._load_nc(file_name)
        else:
            self._load_txt(file_name)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def _load_nc(self, file_name):
        """ Simule le chargement et affichage à partir d'un fichier nc """
        path='D:/stage2019/air.departure.sig995.2012.nc'


        nc = Dataset('./air.departure.sig995.2012.nc')
        lons = nc.variables['lon'][:]
        lats = nc.variables['lat'][:]
        air_dep = nc.variables['air_dep'][:,:,:]
        air_dep = air_dep[0,:,:]

        self.axes.pcolormesh(air_dep)


        self.RS = RectangleSelector(self.axes,self.line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                       button=[1, 3],minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True, rectprops = dict(facecolor='None',edgecolor='red',alpha=5,fill=False))


    def line_select_callback(self, eclick, erelease):
        'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
        x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
        self.zoom_axes=[x1,x2,y1,y2]

    # Zoom is a global variable set in MiddlePanelTop __init__
        #Zoom.Update(self.zoom_axes)
        self.GrandParent.middle.top.Update(self.zoom_axes)



class LeftPanelBottom(wx.Panel):
     def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="LeftBottom", style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER,size = (510,350) )
        self.SetBackgroundColour('snow2')
        panel_buttons = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_buttons_sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        self.canvas_panel = wx.Panel()
        #self.canvas_panel = LeftPanelTop(self)
        #self.zoom_panel = MiddlePanelTop(parent=self)
        select_button = PickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc",
            #self.canvas_panel.load_from_file,
            self.Parent.top.load_from_file,
            label="Open file",)
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(select_button)
        panel_buttons.SetSizer(panel_buttons_sizer)
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        #canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel_buttons)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()


class PickButton(wx.Button):
    """ Bouton permettant de choisir un fichier """

    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, func, **kwargs):
        # func est la méthode à laquelle devra être foruni le fichier sélectionné
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.wildcard = wildcard
        self.func = func
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pick_file)

    def pick_file(self, evt):
        style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.FD_MULTIPLE
        with wx.FileDialog(
            self, "Pick files", wildcard=self.wildcard, style=style
        ) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() != wx.ID_CANCEL:
                chosen_file = fileDialog.GetPath()
                self.func(chosen_file)

# ------------ MIDDLE ------------
class MiddlePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="Middle")
        self.top = MiddlePanelTop(self)
        self.bottom = MiddlePanelBottom(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.top, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MiddlePanelTop(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="MiddleTop", style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER,size = (300,200))

    def Update(self,zoom_axes):
        #Load axis values of the selected rectangle
        #zoom_axes=parent.zoom_axes

        #duplicate the plot from the main panel
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(5,3))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        #Apply axis of drawn rectangle to the plot
        self.axes.axis(zoom_axes)

        path='./air.departure.sig995.2012.nc'


        nc = Dataset('./air.departure.sig995.2012.nc')
        lons = nc.variables['lon'][:]
        lats = nc.variables['lat'][:]
        air_dep = nc.variables['air_dep'][:,:,:]
        air_dep = air_dep[0,:,:]

        self.axes.pcolormesh(air_dep)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.Refresh()



class MiddlePanelBottom(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, name="MiddleBottom", style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        canal=wx.Button(self,-1,"Variable",size=(140,30),pos=(100,0))
        dynamique=wx.Button(self,-1,"Dynamique",size=(140,30),pos=(240,0))
        file = wx.Button(self,-1,"File", size = (110,30),pos=(0,0))
        dynamique.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        canal.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        file.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        dynamique.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        file.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpen)
        self.load_options = "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc| Text files (txt) |*.txt| All files |*.*"

    def onOpen(self, event):
        wildcard = "netCDF4 files (*.nc)|*.nc"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open netCDF4 Files", wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return
        path = dialog.GetPath()

        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path) as fobj:
                for line in fobj:
                    self.my_text.WriteText(line)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Enter Dynamique of image','Dynamique de image')

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         self.text.SetValue("Dynamique:"+dlg.GetValue())
        dlg.Destroy()



# ------------ RIGHT ------------

class RightPanelTop(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        canal=wx.Button(self,-1,"Variable",size=(140,30),pos=(100,0))
        dynamique=wx.Button(self,-1,"Dynamique",size=(140,30),pos=(240,0))
        file = wx.Button(self,-1,"File", size = (110,30),pos=(0,0))
        dynamique.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        canal.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        file.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        dynamique.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        file.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpen)

    def onOpen(self, event):
        wildcard = "netCDF4 files (*.nc)|*.nc| HDF5 files (*.h5) |*.h5"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open netCDF4 Files| HDF5 files", wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return

        path = dialog.GetPath()

        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path) as fobj:
                for line in fobj:
                    self.my_text.WriteText(line)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Enter Dynamique of image','Dynamique de image')

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         self.text.SetValue("Dynamique:"+dlg.GetValue())
        dlg.Destroy()

class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        top = RightPanelTop(self)
        bottom = RightPanelBottom(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(top, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class PanelBottom(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('grey77')

class PanelTop(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        left = SubPanelLeft(self)
        right = SubPanelRight(self)
        midlle = SubPanelMiddle(self)
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer1.Add(left, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer1.Add(midlle, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer1.Add(right, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer1)

class RightPanelBottom(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('snow2')

        top = PanelTop(self)
        bottom = PanelBottom(self)
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer1.Add(top, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer1.Add(bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer1)


class SubPanelLeft(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')

class SubPanelMiddle(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')

class SubPanelRight(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')




app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you i have question if i want to change position of the button "Openfile" where i can add  `pos = (20,50)` ? thank you that woork

Comment: You can't because it is positioned via a `GridSizer`  defined as 1 row with 2 columns. Use `panel_buttons_sizer.Add((-1,-1))` before adding the `select_button` and the button will position in the second column, because you have now put something in the first column.

Comment: okey but if i don't want use GridSizer i can remove and add just `panel_buttons_sizer.Add((-1,-1))` ? thank you

Comment: i'm in Linux and when i run the app in windows i don't have any problem but when i run the app in linux i have this problem but i can show the app

Comment: this is the error ` wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_widget" failed at /tmp/build/80754af9/wxpython_1547931003892/work/ext/wxWidgets/src/gtk/window.cpp(2857) in DoSetSize(): invalid window The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: SystemError: <class 'wx._core.PaintEvent'> returned a result with an error set`

Comment: @TieraEyek Looks like a bug deep in wxwidgets. I assume that it continues to run, even if it reports an internal problem.

Comment: is normal cause i can run the app and all is good the problem is for position of button openfile that all i need to change GridSize !